# Как валидацию формы Yii2 сделать "REAL ONCHANGE"?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Имеется валидация формы, расположенной во вьюшке, код которой ниже. Валидирует неплохо, но только по факту щелчка мышью вне поля формы или по нажатию *Enter*. Нужна такая же валидация, только по факту набора символов в любом поле *input*. Как поправить? желательно, в пределах кода вьюшки. Замена `inputNotNull.change` на `inputNotNull.input` не помогает - в этом случае не работает совсем.

***views/contact/_form.php***:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Contact */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

$myJs = <<<JS
    var inputNotNull = $("input.inputNotNull");
    var email = $("#contact-email_address");
    var empty;
    var re = /.+@.+\..+/i;
    
    inputNotNull.change(function() {
        var email_value = email.val();
        var validemail = re.test(email_value);
        
        inputNotNull.each(function(){
            
            if(($(this).val() !== "") && (validemail)){
                $('#my_button')[0].disabled = 0;
            } else {
                $('#my_button')[0].disabled = 1;
                return false;
            } 
            $('#my_button')[0].disabled = empty;
          });
    });
JS;

$this->registerJs($myJs);

?>

<div class="contact-search">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Имя   ') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'middle_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control'])->label('Отчество') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'internal_phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Вн.номер') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile_phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Моб.номер') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email_address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'class' => 'form-control inputNotNull'])->label('Email') ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Добавить', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'test-button',
            'id' => 'my_button', 'disabled' => 'disabled', /*'onclick' => '$("#my_button").attr("disabled", "disabled")'*/]) ?>

    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Прочитать про событие `keypress`

Comment: @phpBear, работает. спасибо. вдогонку - почему метод `inputNotNull.input` не работает?)

Comment: К сожалению не вижу как Вы реализовали перехват этого события. Возможно в нем где-то ошибка. Раз уж Вы используете не `pureJS`, а `jQuery` то попробуйте через перехватчик события `.on` навешать свою функцию - 'inputNotNull.on('input', function() { ... })'. Также возможно у Вас используется `pjax` и тогда есть вариант, что перехват события после `pjax:send` теряется так как навешан на элемент `DOM` который после `pjax:complete` перезаписывается - в таком случае вешайте обработчик на `document` с селектором `input`